Can't get more than 90 score performance mobile
I would like some help regarding the optimization of my website developed with WordPress. I have installed the Blankslate theme, and I created a child theme to develop my portfolio site. My site is almost finished, and I am currently optimizing it. I have tried minifying and combining my code, and I have also tried loading scripts and styles with defer and async, but it doesn't make much difference. I have also compressed and optimized my images. The only issue, as I mentioned earlier, is that my score is around 70-80 on mobile. I have done a lot of audits today, and there were rare times when I reached 95. Regarding the desktop version, I have a very good score of around 97-98. I have just added a CDN, but it still hasn't solved my problem.
Audit Detail
Audit
I have compressed and optimized my images.
I have used a CDN.
I have optimized the JS and CSS with W3 Total Cache.

This looks to be a very well optimized page. Getting 90+ on Lighthouse performance score is not easy and requires either a very light site, or advanced techniques. At this point you're usually better concentrating on Real User Monitoring (RUM) data as Lighthouse only provides so much value in the top end.
The main thing that jumps our to me is that 84.2% of your site is due to the 861,616 bytes needed to load the 6 fonts on your site. That's a whole lotta fonts that will take up resources (network and CPU) to download and process. You might want to subset them, or for Helvetica do you really need a web font as the default sans-serif font is pretty close to that.
